# autocomplete list loading but not showing in IE 9, 10 and 11

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

My **kendo autocomplete** widget is configured to use **Ajax** to retrieve a list of customers which it does successfully and this all works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it's behaving strangely.

1. In IE F12 tools I monitored the network activity, saw the Ajax call
   successfully return with json data.
2. I also checked the HTML tab and saw that the records returned in json were correctly created as HTML elements in the DOM

Only problem is that the drop down listbox part is not actually being shown.

Here's the listbox HTML before Kendo creates each list item element from the json data:

```
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="clientSearchInput-list" style="display: none; position: absolute;" data-role="popup">
    <ul tabindex="-1" class="k-list k-reset" id="clientSearchInput_listbox" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="polite" style="overflow: auto;" unselectable="on"></ul>
</div>
```

Here's the same listbox after Kendo has created the list items:

```
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" id="clientSearchInput-list" style="height: 200px; display: none; position: absolute;" data-role="popup">
    <ul tabindex="-1" class="k-list k-reset" id="clientSearchInput_listbox" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="polite" style="overflow: auto;" unselectable="on">
        <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item k-state-focused" id="clientSearchInput_option_selected" role="option" unselectable="on">oRaNo SpeKER (SYGAA1501)</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" class="k-item" role="option" unselectable="on">Halthegorth Feirae (SYGAA0531)</li>
        <li ...>... many more items</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So everything actually works up till this point. But looking at the style element of the outer div container I noticed this part:

```
style="...; display: none; ..."
```

It seems like Kendo is stopping at the point of actually showing the listbox. I would also expected to see additional values in there for top and left once Kendo has worked out where the listbox should be displayed.

Lastly, there are no exceptions in the console.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Kendo UI package to the newest version.

Comment: was that just a standard answer or is there a reference to this being a bug in a particular version of Kendo?

Comment: i was facing some problem in rendering combox and autocomplete list in ie 8, 9 & 10, after some digin, i change my all kendo js files by upgrading kendo package.. it works.. yes this is not a standard answer but you may refer to some telerik blog like this http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-scrollbar-does-not-work-with-ie-9.. i hope this will help you..

Comment: only problem is that this was working before. The major difference is that before I was creating the DataSource object, assigning it to the auto complete widget, then manually calling Fetch at page startup to get the entire list downloaded to the client. That suggests that it isn't necessarily a version issue. ?